# Why is my DQN training with tensorflow becoming slower each iteration?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I’m trying to implement a DQN with experience replay in tensorflow. It seems to be working, i.e. my loss is decreasing. However, as the the training loop is running I’ve noticed that each training iteration becomes slower and slower. It is as if my tensorflow graph is becoming bigger and bigger and slowing down the training. I cannot see myself what the problem with my code is. Any tensorflow guru out there that can point it out? I have made a scaled-down version of my code here which operates on random data but produces the same issue.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Function which initializes tensorflow weights for feed-forward NN.
def InitWeights(LayerSizes):
    # Make tensorflow input/output placeholders    
    X = tf.placeholder(shape = (None,LayerSizes[0]),  dtype = tf.float32, name ='InputData')
    y = tf.placeholder(shape = (None,LayerSizes[-1]), dtype = tf.float32, name ='OutputData')
    # Initialize dictionaries for weights and biases.
    W = {}
    b = {}
    for ii in range(len(LayerSizes)-1):
        layername = f'layer%s' % ii
        with tf.variable_scope(layername):
            ny = LayerSizes[ii]
            nx = LayerSizes[ii+1]
            # Weights (initialized with xavier initializatiion).
            W['Weights_'+layername] = tf.get_variable(
                                name = 'Weights_'+layername,
                                shape = (ny, nx),
                                initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(),
                                dtype = tf.float32
                                )
            # Bias (initialized with xavier initializatiion).
            b['Bias_'+layername] = tf.get_variable(
                                name = 'Bias_'+layername,
                                shape = (nx),
                                initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(),
                                dtype = tf.float32
                                )
    return W, b, X, y

# Function which defines feed-forward neural network operation.
def FeedForward(X, W, b):
    a = X
    # Loop all layers of the network.
    for ii in range(len(W)):
        # Use name of each layer as index.
        layername = f'layer%s' % ii
        # Weighted sum: z = input*W + b
        z = tf.add(tf.matmul(a, W['Weights_'+layername], name = 'WeightedSum_z_'+layername), b['Bias_'+layername])
        # Passed through actication fcn: a = h(z)
        if ii == len(W)-1:
            a = z
        else:
            a = tf.nn.relu(z, name = 'activation_a_'+layername)
    return a

# Function used for experience replay   
def ExperienceReplay(s, a, r, s_prime, gamma, TermState, X, y, yhat, yhatNN2, train_op, loss, sess):
    # Inputs:
    # s         - state(s)
    # a         - actions(s)
    # r         - rewards(s)
    # s_prime   - new state(s)
    # gamma     - discount factor
    # TermState - scalar of which action is termenating 
    # X         - tensorflow placeholder for network inputs
    # y         - tensorflow placeholder for network outputs
    # yhat      - tensorflow operation for feed foward with NN 1
    # yhatNN2   - tensorflow operation for feed foward with NN 2
    # train_op  - tensorflow training operation
    # loss      - tensorflow fcn for calculating loss
    # sess      - tensorflow session

    # Forward pass throught NN2 using s_prime to find max(Q(s',a',theta')).
    Q = sess.run(yhatNN2, feed_dict={X : s_prime}) 

    # Actions that NN1 thinks is best @ sprime state
    a_argmax = np.argmax(sess.run(yhat, feed_dict={X : s_prime}), axis=1)
    # Values from NN2's opinion about the actions NN1 picked.
    Qm = np.zeros(len(r))
    for obs in range(len(r)):
        Qm[obs] = Q[obs,a_argmax[obs]]

    # First make all targets equal to NN1's approximation of Q (so the error is 0 in all unobserved cases) 
    Targets = sess.run(yhat, feed_dict={X : s})

    # If the action was experienced, change the target to either real reward or discounted future reward.
    for obs in range(len(r)):
        # If the action was episode-terminating, use only reward as target.
        if int(a[obs]) == TermState:
            Targets[obs,int(a[obs])] = r[obs]
        # Otherwise use discounted future reward.
        else:
            Targets[obs,int(a[obs])] = r[obs] + gamma*Qm[obs]

    # Gradient decent one step on NN1 weights.
    sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X : s, y : Targets})

    # Calculate the losses.
    loss_val = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={X : s, y : Targets})
    meanloss = np.mean(loss_val)

    return loss_val, meanloss


if __name__ == "__main__":

    #### Hyperparameter settings
    N         = 64     # Minibatch size during training
    gamma     = 0.99   # Discount rate
    C         = 100    # How many iterations between NN sync NN2 = NN1
    lr        = 1e-7   # Learning rate of NN during training
    nstates   = 256    # Number of possible states
    nactions  = 256    # Number of possible actions
    TermState = 255    # Which state ends episode
    """
    Initialize tensorflow session and create one NN with two set of weights
    """
    # Initialize & configure action-value function Q with random weights theta.
    LayerSizes = [nstates, 1024, 1024, nactions]
    W, b, X, y = InitWeights(LayerSizes)

    # Define loss function to optimize. Here: quadratic loss fcn. (Outputdata-a)^2
    yhat = FeedForward(X, W, b)
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y - yhat),reduction_indices=[0])

    # Define optimizer to use when minimizing loss function.
    all_variables = tf.trainable_variables()
    optimizer     = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = lr)
    train_op      = optimizer.minimize(loss, var_list = all_variables)

    # Initialize target action-value function Qhat with random weights theta_= theta.
    with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
        W2 = {}
        b2 = {}
        # Make hard copy of tensorflow Weights and biases
        for key in W:
            W2[key] = tf.Variable(W[key].initialized_value())
        for key in b:
            b2[key] = tf.Variable(b[key].initialized_value())
        yhatNN2 = FeedForward(X, W2, b2)

    # Start tf session and initialize variables.
    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    ## Generate random data representing state transitions <s,a,r,s'>.
    # Random states
    Ds       = np.random.rand(100000,nstates)>0.5
    Ds       = Ds.astype(np.float32)
    # Random actions
    Da       = np.random.randint(0,nstates,(100000,1)).astype(np.float32)
    # Random rewards
    Dr       = np.random.rand(100000,1).astype(np.float32)
    # Random new states
    Ds_prime  = np.random.rand(100000,nstates)>0.5
    Ds_prime  = Ds.astype(np.float32)

    """
    Pretrain network and report time each C iterations
    """
    import time
    t0 = time.time()
    for i in range(100000):
        # Randomly pick minibatch to use
        MemsToUse = np.random.choice(len(Dr), N)
        s      = Ds[MemsToUse,:]
        a      = Da[MemsToUse,0]
        r      = Dr[MemsToUse,0]
        sprime = Ds_prime[MemsToUse,:]

        # Experience replay.
        loss_val, meanloss = ExperienceReplay(s, a, r, sprime, gamma,TermState, X, y, yhat, yhatNN2, train_op, loss, sess)

        # every C iteration copy NN2 = NN1 
        if (i % C) == 0:
            t1 = time.time()
            print('iter: %i meanloss: %0.5f iteration took %0.2f s' %(i,meanloss,t1-t0))
            t0 = time.time()
            with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
                for key in W:
                    W2[key] = tf.Variable(W[key].initialized_value())
                for key in b:
                    b2[key] = tf.Variable(b[key].initialized_value())
```

Update: After having timed individual segments of the code it appears as if it’s the first line of my Experience replay function:

```
Q = sess.run(yhatNN2, feed_dict={X : s_prime})
```

That is causing most if not all of the slowdown. I don’t understand the logic behind why that is, there are several feedforward passes occurring in the program but only this one seem to cause a problem..

Comment: Try tracking the time between relevant portions of the `for-loop` so you can determine WHERE it's happening then instead ask why that portion of the code is slowing down? I upvoted you because you definitely put effort into it by giving us a MCVE but I don't think determining where it's happening requires a TF guru

Comment: That’s a very good idea, I didn’t even think of that. I have now timed separate parts of the script and identified one particular line that’s problematic. I still however don’t understand why it is causing a problem.

Comment: Running into a similar problem myself, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Azmisov My ‘solution’ was to transition into using Keras instead of tensorflow directly. Is solves many of the annoying problems such as the one posted here.